# Common start for url in all paths in team

Tags: python, django, url, architecture, django-urls

I'm just working on a project in Django 1.11.
I have a problem with how to make a common beginning of the url.
For example, after creating a team, the address for all members should look like this:

```
domain.com/name_of_team
domain.com/name_of_team/blog
domain.com/name_of_team/blog/title_of_post
```

Main url file in project:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Urls in blog:

```
url(r'^$', login_required(RedirectToHome.as_view()), name='redirect_home'),
url(r'^t/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(BlogHome.as_view()), name='blog_list'),
url(r'create/$', login_required(BlogCreate.as_view()), name='blog_create'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$', login_required(BlogDelete.as_view()), name='blog_delete'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', login_required(BlogUpdate.as_view()), name='blog_update'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)?/?$', login_required(BlogDetail.as_view()), name='blog_detail'),
```

Maybe there are some good practices for dealing with url addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the blog application specific to each team you could include it's URLs with;

```
url(r'^(?P<team_slug>[\w-]+)/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog')),
```

This obviously assumes that your `Team` model has a `slug` field so that you can safely add it to the context & use it to form your URLs for the `blog` application.

You could then have a `Mixin` that could be shared by views in the blog or add something to a shared base view which loads the `Team`

```
from django.views.generic.base import ContextMixin

from .models import Team


class TeamMixin(ContextMixin):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TeamMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['team'] = Team.objects.get(slug=kwargs.get('team_slug'))
        return context
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This approch is also OK when I want to add another apps for example `topics`?

Comment: Yeah this would be fairly generic & you could use that type of mixin anywhere you'd want to include the `team_slug` in the URL

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think I will write this in new app, to seperate blog and topic app.